Where am I making a mistake with this hypothesis test in Python?
I have the following measurements for body temperature:

99.6
97.8
98.7
99.2
99.1
96.9
99.9
98.7
97.6
98.7
99.2
97.4 99 98
98.8
98.1 99
98.2
97.9
99.5
97.7
97.8
98.3 98
98.6
96.9
98.6
98.4
98.3 98
97.9
98.8
98.8
98.7
97.2
97.7
98.2
96.4
98.8
98.2 98
98.8
98.8
98.5
98.3
97.7
98.2
98.4 100
98.2
98.9
97.8 99
98.6
98.7
98.7
98.8
98.4
97.9
98.4
99.3
100.8
99.4
97.8
98.8
97.2
98.4
98.2 97 98
98.2
98.3
98.6
98.8
99.2
96.8
98.4 98
97.6
98.4
98.9
97.1
97.4
98.8
96.8 97
98.2
97.8
97.9
98.5
98.6
97.8 98
98.6
97.7
97.8
98.2
97.4 97
97.6
98.8
97.2 97
98.8
98.4
98.3
99.1
97.6
97.3 98 97
98.7
99.4 98
98.4
98.6 98
98.1 99
99.2
97.4
97.5
98.5
97.4
96.6
98.1
98.6
98.4
98.8
97.5
98.2
96.2
98.4
98.2
97.3
98.6 99 99
98.6
98.2 98
97.9
98.4
97.8 98
99.2
98.7
98.3

And then my assignment asks

Is the mean body temperature equal to $98.6^\circ$F? Run a hypothesis
test to find out.  Then construct a confidence interval on the mean.

This is a "Stats in Python" class so all solutions are with Python code.  The above data is read into a Pandas dataframe called temps.
My null is that the mean is equal to 98.6 and the alternative is just that it's not equal (i.e. a two-sided test).
I start with
# Test
alpha = 0.05
# determine the sample size
n = len(temps["BodyTemp"])
# determine the sample standard deviation
s = statistics.stdev(temps["BodyTemp"])
# and sample mean
xbar = statistics.mean(temps["BodyTemp"])
# calculate our test statistic
t = (xbar - 98.6)/(s* math.sqrt(n))
print(t)

This yields a test statistic of -0.04073692590024498.  Then...
# Critical Value
# for a two sided test we use alpha/2
tcrit = stats.t.ppf(q=1-(alpha/2),df=n-1)
print(tcrit)

Which yields 1.9762333088845878.  $t < tcrit$, fail to reject the null that the mean is 98.6.
But on the confidence interval I come up with
# Confidence Interval
# for a confidence interval we use alpha over 2
tconf = stats.t.ppf(q=1-(alpha/2),df=n-1)
half_width = (tconf * s)/math.sqrt(n)
low = xbar - half_width
high = xbar + half_width
print("(", low, ", ", high, ")")

Which yields a confidence interval of (98.115, 98.354) where I would have expected 98.6 to be in the interval.  Obviously I'm goofing this up somewhere but I'm failing to spot where.

Notice how in your first block of code you have s * math.sqrt(n) and in your last block you have, in effect, s / math.sqrt(n)....

From what I understand, your CI is fine, but your test statistic is wrong. More specifically, t in the first code block should be
t = math.sqrt(n)*(xbar - 98.6)/s
instead of
t = (xbar - 98.6)/(s* math.sqrt(n)),
since
t = (xbar - 98.6)/(s / math.sqrt(n)) = math.sqrt(n)*(xbar - 98.6)/s.
In essence, you are multiplying s by math.sqrt(n) instead of dividing it by math.sqrt(n), which would be the correct approach.
A formal way to understand this is to see that the correct standard error for the sample mean, $\bar{X}$, is equal to $\sqrt{\mathrm{var}(\bar{X})} = \sigma^2/\sqrt{n}$, which would be estimated by $S/\sqrt{n}$ (giving rise to the Student's t distribution for $\bar{X}$) instead of $S \cdot \sqrt{n}$, where $S$ denotes the sample standard error.

Making that change yields a t statistic of -6.03.  So the correct interpretation is that since the absolute value of that is greater than the critical value of 1.976 we reject the null, correct?  Then we're consistent with the confidence interval...

Exactly! Reiterating your first impression: if you build a CI inverting the acceptance region of a hypothesis test, their conclusions should be exactly the same.
